# Service undefine Cannot read property 'saveFormJson' of undefined in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing, angular7, angular2-services

Here buttons are dynamic and i have inject service in constructor and also bind as provider then also when i debug it service got undefined and show error like cannot read property "saveFormJson".

Here i mention code so in this component file i have one action button and when click event trigger i want to use that service which is i got null.

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { config, defaultOptions, defaultI18n } from './config';
import { FormBuilderCreateor } from './form-builder';
import I18N from './mi18n';
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
import {DataService} from '../formsList/services/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-formBuilder',
    templateUrl: './formBuilder.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./formBuilder.component.scss' ],
    animations: [routerTransition()],
    providers: [DataService]

})


export class FormBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  public myService: any;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

  formBuilder: any;
    ngOnInit(): void {
      initJq();
      var actionButtons = [
        {
          id: "smile",
          className: "btn btn-success",
          label: "",
          type: "button",
          events: {
            click: function () {
              this.dataService.saveFormJson("[{}]");
            }
          }
        }
      ];
      this.formBuilder = (<any>jQuery('.build-wrap')).formBuilder({ actionButtons: actionButtons});
      console.log(this.formBuilder);
    }
}
```

Here i mention service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { FormTemplate } from '../models/formTemplate';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private readonly API_URL = 'http://localhost:61831/api/FormTemplates/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private toasterService: ToastrService) { }

saveFormJson(formJson: JSON): void {
      this.httpClient.post(this.API_URL +"/SaveFormJson ",formJson).subscribe(data => {
        this.toasterService.success('Form Builder Successfully created', "Form Builder");
      },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.toasterService.error('Error occurred. Details: ' + err.name + ' ' + err.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Here i mention module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilderRoutingModule } from './formBuilder-routing.module';
import { FormBuilderComponent } from './formBuilder.component';
import { PageHeaderModule } from '../../shared';
import { DataService } from '../formsList/services/data.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormBuilderRoutingModule, PageHeaderModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [FormBuilderComponent],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class FormBuilderModule {}
```

So please guide me to proper way to use service in component file .
Thank you

Comment: you called it `dataService` not `myService`. `myService` is an undefined variable, whereas `dataService` is the name of your service

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I have change mention code that is by mistake this is not actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies here. Please use `=>` because `this` arrow functions don't have its own `this` and its points to the class `this`.
If you use `function` then it have its own `this` and it can't access class `this`

```
events: {
    click: () =>  { // change to arrow function
      this.dataService.saveFormJson("[{}]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code as below:

`this.myService.saveFormJson("[{}]");` to `this.dataService.saveFormJson("[{}]");`

Comment: I have edit code which is i mention but this is not problem